# brave and chromium browsers unresponsive on virtualbox arch guest

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, chrome

Installed `brave.bin` from aur without error. The browser comes up okay but the menu and search bar are unresponsive for several minutes. After that performance is very slow.

Network and all applications tried show excellent performance.

```
 Brave  Version 1.39.111 Chromium: 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

I installed chromium into the same VM and have the same issue.

Host

```
 Arch up to date with 5.18.3/ 32 GB RAM 
 VBox Version "6.1.34"/
```

Guest

```
   Arch up to date with 5.18.3
    <Memory RAMSize="8192"/>
    <Display controller="VBoxSVGA" VRAMSize="128"/>
      <CPU count="4">
        <PAE enabled="false"/>
        <LongMode enabled="true"/>
        <X2APIC enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
```

Errors from journal

```
libva error: vaGetDriverNameByIndex() failed with unknown libva error, driver_name = (null)
[200702:200702:0612/191103.698873:ERROR:gpu_memory_buffer_support_x11.cc(44)] dri3 extension not supported.
[200641:200641:0612/191107.684154:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 2.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
[200641:200641:0612/191107.684251:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 2.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
[200641:200641:0612/191107.685016:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 2.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
[200641:200641:0612/191107.701868:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 2.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
```

Comment: Try to activate "Nested VT-x/AMD-V". At least it helped me.